# Removing a key stuck in a SmartKey lock

Tags: lock

Is there a way to remove a key that is stuck in a SmartKey lock?

I inserted the key as usual, but it wouldn't turn and then couldn't even be removed.  (It had worked okay a few minutes before, and no one had tampered with it in the meantime.)

Note that I already know how to remove a SmartKey cylinder and rekey it without having the original key.  That isn't what I'm asking about.

Comment: I think I understand like someone stuck something in it and now you can’t get the key out correct?   I was able to use a heat gun one time someone put lock tight in a lock and the tumblers were stiff going in but the key would not come out. I heated it up and was able to get the key out but did have to dissemble the lock to free up the mechanism, a neighbor had a locksmith out and he has some spray that cleared it with out all the heat and taking apart but I don’t remember what it was.  a kid was doing this to several homes in our area including his parents, I was glad when he got caught.

Comment: @EdBeal, thanks, but it had worked okay a few minutes before, and no one had tampered with it in the meantime.

Comment: Is it in the open condition or the closed condition?  Do you have access to the rear?  Can you remove the entire cylinder and key, and thus access the keyway?
Do you have the programming pin available?

Comment: Try inserting the rekey pin again and then performing the rekeying process.

Comment: @Bryce, yes, I've already put in a replacement lock. I'd just like the old one to be more useful than a paperweight.

Comment: @BMitch, the pin won't help.  It can't be inserted without rotating the cylinder 90°, which is stuck in the normal position and won't turn.

Comment: I've had these looks get stuck on weird states because the slider that the pin activates doesn't fully return to the keyed state. It won't hurt the lock any worse to try.